# Set listener for Stage click

Tags: javascript, konvajs

**WARNING: turn the volume down before you run the snippet!**

I want to be able to click on the stage to add a 'module' shape. But I have found that a click on the 'module' shape itself creates another, meaning that the stage.click listener is being fired when it should not be.

How can I have a stage.click listener that does not fire incorrectly when I click on a shape ?

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var rectButtonClicked  = false;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();

var group = new Konva.Group({
  draggable: true
});

stage.on('contentClick', function() {
  createModule();
});

function createModule() {

  var mouseX = stage.getPointerPosition().x;
  var mouseY = stage.getPointerPosition().y;

  var rect = new Konva.Rect({ //module rect
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    cornerRadius: 5,
    fill: '#BEDBDD',
    stroke: '#807C7B',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    draggable: true
  });
  group.add(rect);

    var buttonRect = new Konva.Rect({ //button
    x: mouseX+80,
    y: mouseY+20,
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    cornerRadius: 1,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: '#807C7B',
    strokeWidth: 1,
  });
  group.add(buttonRect)

  var text = new Konva.Text({  //text on module
    x: mouseX + 20,
    y: mouseY + 20,
    //fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fontSize: 16,
    text: 'OSC',
    fill: 'black'
  });
  group.add(text);

  var randomFreq = getRandomInt();
  var osc = new Tone.Oscillator(randomFreq, "sawtooth");
  layer.add(group);
  stage.add(layer);

  buttonRect.on('click', function() {
    rectButtonClicked = !rectButtonClicked;
    if(rectButtonClicked){    
    osc.toMaster().start();
    this.setFill('red');
    }  else {
    osc.stop();
    this.setFill('blue');
    }  
});
}

function getRandomInt() {
  min = Math.ceil(100);
  max = Math.floor(1000);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

//var drag = false;
var rectButtonClicked  = false;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();

var group = new Konva.Group({
  draggable: true
});

stage.on('contentClick', function() {
  createModule();
});

function createModule() {

  var mouseX = stage.getPointerPosition().x;
  var mouseY = stage.getPointerPosition().y;

  var rect = new Konva.Rect({ //module rect
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    cornerRadius: 5,
    fill: '#BEDBDD',
    stroke: '#807C7B',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    draggable: true
  });
  group.add(rect);
  
    var buttonRect = new Konva.Rect({ //button
    x: mouseX+80,
    y: mouseY+20,
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    cornerRadius: 1,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: '#807C7B',
    strokeWidth: 1,
  });
  group.add(buttonRect)
  
  var text = new Konva.Text({  //text on module
    x: mouseX + 20,
    y: mouseY + 20,
    //fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fontSize: 16,
    text: 'OSC',
    fill: 'black'
  });
  group.add(text);
  
  var randomFreq = getRandomInt();
  var osc = new Tone.Oscillator(randomFreq, "sawtooth");
  layer.add(group);
  stage.add(layer);
  
  buttonRect.on('click', function() {
    rectButtonClicked = !rectButtonClicked;
    if(rectButtonClicked){    
    osc.toMaster().start();
    this.setFill('red');
    }  else {
    osc.stop();
    this.setFill('blue');
    }  
});
}

function getRandomInt() {
  min = Math.ceil(100);
  max = Math.floor(1000);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://tonejs.github.io/build/Tone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.6/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stage.contentClick() listener is a special case to be used when you want the stage to listen to events on the stage content. However, the cancelBubble() function does not stop events bubbling from say a click on a shape to the stage.contentClick() listener.

To get the effect that you want, which is to give the impression that a click on the stage has happened, you need to add a rect that fills the stage and listen for events on that rect instead of the stage.

Below is a working example. The red background I added deliberately so you know there is something else above the stage. To remove this take out the fill color on the clickRect.

I also fixed up your buttons so that the contents are correctly grouped and drag together. You were almost correct but you needed the group to be created within in the createModule() function.  You can see that I also made the group elements dragabble = false to complete the process.

I added a couple of console writes to show when the events fire.

[Also I got quite a shock when I switched on the tone for tone].

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

//var drag = false;
var rectButtonClicked  = false;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var clickRect =  new Konva.Rect({ 
  x:0,
  y:0,
  width: width,
  height: height,
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: '#807C7B',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  listening: 'true'  
})
layer.add(clickRect);

clickRect.on('click', function() {
  console.log('Stage click');
  createModule();
});

function createModule() {
  var group = new Konva.Group({ // move group create into createModule
    draggable: true  // we will make the elements not draggable - we drag the group
  });

  var mouseX = stage.getPointerPosition().x;
  var mouseY = stage.getPointerPosition().y;

  var rect = new Konva.Rect({ //module rect
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    cornerRadius: 5,
    fill: '#BEDBDD',
    stroke: '#807C7B',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    draggable: false // make the element not draggable - we drag the group
  });
  group.add(rect);
  
  rect.on('click', function(evt){
  console.log('Clicked on button');
  })
  
    var buttonRect = new Konva.Rect({ //button
    x: mouseX+80,
    y: mouseY+20,
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    cornerRadius: 1,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: '#807C7B',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    listening: true,
    draggable: false  // make the element not draggable - we drag the group
  });
  group.add(buttonRect)

  var text = new Konva.Text({  //text on module
    x: mouseX + 20,
    y: mouseY + 20,
    //fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fontSize: 16,
    text: 'OSC',
    fill: 'black',
    draggable: false  // make the element not draggable - we drag the group
  });
  group.add(text);
  
  var randomFreq = getRandomInt();
  var osc = new Tone.Oscillator(randomFreq, "sawtooth");
  layer.add(group);
  stage.add(layer);

  buttonRect.on('click', function(evt) {
    rectButtonClicked = !rectButtonClicked;
    if(rectButtonClicked){    
    osc.toMaster().start();
    this.setFill('red');
    }  else {
    osc.stop();
    this.setFill('blue');
    }  
});
}

function getRandomInt() {
  min = Math.ceil(100);
  max = Math.floor(1000);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
stage.draw(); // draw so we can see click rect.
```

```html
<script src="https://tonejs.github.io/build/Tone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.6/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="background-color: gold;"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry about the sound! Just added a warning.